# Apache redirect all to index.php except for existing files and folders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have index.php that reads full path by `$_SERVER[‘REQUEST_URI’]` variable. My task is when user enter: `www.domain/resource/777` redirect to `index.php` with path `/resource/777` and parse `$_SERVER[‘REQUEST_URI’]` to do some logic. But I have also real files and folders like:

- css/theme.css
- assets/assets.js
- resource/locale.js

When I try this config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

Client could not get all css and etc files. How to write correct rule in Apache to achive this?

Comment: Hmmm, that config usually works for me.  Can you give more info.  Did some css files work but not others?  Or did all css files not work.  Is the config in an .htaccess file or in the httpd.conf?

Comment: I got 404 Not Found on all files. Config in httpd.conf. Real example: http://lib.c.nis.edu.kz/resource/5

Comment: Thanks for the link to your page.  When I sent a request for one of your .js files, the response headers say that your web server is nginx/1.8.0.  The RewriteCond, etc are Apache config, not nginx.  Which web server are you running?

Comment: Nginx is on top of Apache. Nginx just proxy pass to apache 88 port.

Comment: Im not an expect, but isn't the rules above is saying to redirect all request file to `index.php` and `index.php` is not a `css` nor a `js` file??

Comment: @Andrew:  The 2 rewrite conditions (RewriteCond) determine if the RewriteRule is executed.  Kinda like an "if" statement but in Apache's klunky language.  It is saying:  if (request is not (!) an existing directory (-d) AND is not (!) an existing file (-f)) { Rewrite to index.php }.  In other words, if the request is for an existing directory or file, then don't rewrite the rule and so respond with the existing directory or file.

Answer (score 28):

If you are using Apache 2.2.16 or later, you can replace rewrite rules entirely with one single directive:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource

Basically, if a request were to cause an error 404, the fallback resource uri will be used to handle the request instead, correctly populating the `$_SERVER[‘REQUEST_URI’]` variable.

Comment: This works very well. I'd recommend this.

Comment: @JoelBodenmann yeah it works nice I needed:
<Directory /app/public/>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

        # Rewrite all request from example.com/app to app.example.com
        FallbackResource /index.php
    </Directory>
    <Directory /app/public/bundles/>
        FallbackResource disabled
    </Directory>

For API platform framework

Answer (score 3):

Your rule is fine. Issue with css/js/image is that you're using relative path to include them.

You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Also keep just this rule in your .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^.]+$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Didn't work. The problem is I got 404. Real example: http://lib.c.nis.edu.kz/resource/4

Comment: Your `http://lib.c.nis.edu.kz/assets/css/style.css` is throwing 404. What is correct URL for this `css` file?

Comment: That is main problem! These files are exists. RewriteEngine doing something that user can not get these files. If I remove all Rewrite* user can achive these files. But index.php won't get "/resource/4" by $_SERVER[‘REQUEST_URI’]

Comment: Now I can achive files but index.php do not work: http://lib.c.nis.edu.kz/resource/5  I got 404 error

Comment: You're using `Server: nginx/1.8.0` not Apache hence these htaccess rules don't work.

Comment: Nginx is on top of Apache. Nginx just proxy pass to apache 88 port.

Comment: This is definitely some weird setup that's causing simplest possible rule like above to not work. No one can guess what's wrong, only ones who have access to your host can dig into this.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) `REQUEST_FILENAME` only evaluates to the full local filesystem path to the file if the path has already been determined by the server.

In a nutshell this means the condition will work if it is inside an `.htaccess` file or within a `<Directory>` section in your httpd.conf but not if it's just inside a `<VirtualHost>`. In this latter case, you can simply wrap it in a `<Directory>` tag to get it working.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     # ... some other config ...
    <Directory /path/to/your/site>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the error document in your htaccess file so that index.php will be used then a non existing file is requested:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Comment: Could you please tell complete config if it possible?

Comment: @Yoldar-Zi What should your comment tell me? :)

Comment: I mean just to put it at the end of Rewrite* rules?

Answer (score 0):

For now only this helped to me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/src/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/resource/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/data.json
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```