# React Router not functional when deployed in a sub-directory On Apache

Tags: reactjs, apache, react-redux, react-router, subdirectory

I'm having quite an issue deploying my react app to a sub-directory on appache.
I am using create-react-app and React router v4.
When i visit the Url www.example.com/myApp. the html i am rendering as my homepage gets rendered properly.

But if i try to visit the register page by typing the route manually in the address bar, i get a 404 Not found error.

What i have done.

1. I have set the basname of my BrowserRouter to the subdirectory.
2. I have also set the homepage property in package.json.
3. I have created .htaccess file.

Please i have been at this for days trying to figure out what i am doing wrong but i can not seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Apache attempts to find a resource for the requested route. You need to redirect all requests to your index so the react bundle can be loaded and react-router can do its thing

This has been addressed a few times so I'll reference other helpul answers

Change the VirtualHost configuration (typically found in /etc/httpd/conf.d\vhosts.conf) by adding the following Rewrite* lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/httpd/example.com

  <Directory "/var/www/httpd/example.com">
    ...

    RewriteEngine on
    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48872476/4880022)