# When navigating to a URL in a React app I get a 404 but when I follow a link to the same URL I get the right page displayed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've looked through other answers and tried the solutions but I"m still getting a bit confused.

I've got a url, say `www.sitename.com` and I've got a React app using `react-router-dom` to do the routing.

```
      <Router>
        <Route
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/"}
          exact={true}
          component={Home}
        />
        <Route path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/about"} component={About} />
        <Route
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/projects"}
          component={Projects}
        />
        <Route path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/contact"} component={Contact} />
      </Router>
```

I've imported HashRouter as Router in this project.

Other answers I've read say that this will solve the problem I was having of when a page is reloaded, the browser wouldn't be able to display anything as, for example, there was no content at `www.sitename.com/about` as the rendering was controlled from the `index.html` page.

Using the hash router did solve the problem, but now I can't direct people to `www.sitename.com/about` as that page still doesn't exist, React seems to make the URL `www.sitename.com/#/about`

I've read the docs but can't seem to find an answer that makes sense to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are writing a single page application, you aren't really navigating between different HTML documents. Instead, you modify the DOM to show different data.

This *looks* like different pages, but isn't really. This caused all sorts of problems because the browser's back button didn't work and you didn't have different URLs for different "pages".

As a hack, people changed the fragment identifier portion of the page and used JavaScript to work out which section of the SPA should be displayed. As a result, it will put `#`s in the URL so you can't have a URL with `/about` but have `#/about` instead.

This is what `HashRouter` does. **If you just link to `#/about` it will work.**

---

Browser vendors reacted to this by adding [the History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). This provides mechanisms to insert URLs into the browser history and get all the benefits of # based navigation with nice URLs.

It is designed to be used in conjunction with server-side code which has the same effect as the DOM manipulation the JavaScript does.

So if you click a link to `/about`:

1. JavaScript changes the DOM to show the about page
2. JavaScript changes the URL to `/about`

**but** if you visit `/about` directly then the server generates the about page instead.

**This provides good food for search engines and content that is accessible even if the JavaScript fails.**

It is also **more work** since you need to make the server duplicate the work of the client. Happily, there are tools to make this easy. A couple of populate ones are [next.js](https://nextjs.org/) which uses isomorphic JavaScript to make the client-side React code run on the server as well and [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) which generates static pages at build time so you can use static hosting.

They have their own Router modules to use instead of HashRouter.

**If you want to use URLs without a `#`, pages which work even when JavaScript fails, and a bonus to SEO: Use one of those approaches**.

---

There is also the cheap and dirty hack approach which is to configure your HTTP server to serve up the basic HTML document which loads the React JS for *every* URL which isn't a static file.

This then makes it the responsibility of the client-side code to look at the URL and work out what content to show (in the same way that HashRouter does). It also tends to cause lots of URLs which should be 404 errors to return 200 and that basic HTML document.

You'd switch out HashRouter for [BrowserRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter) if you did this.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried to port my site to Gatsby, but I think given that I've come this far it has become too much to change things. I now understand a bit better how an SPA works!

The solution I used in the end, and it's only possible as I've deployed it using Netlify, was to use the Netlify config `.toml` file to redirect all requests to the `index.html` file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, when a client (the browser) ask for a page to the server (for example `/about`) and this page does not exists in the server, it gives a 404.

To solve this problem you should configure your server to return you, for every request, the `/index.html` file that is aware of react-router-dom routing.

To configure your server, assuming you are using Apache, you should follow this answer (you can find similar tutorials also for other web servers):

[How to setup apache server for React route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038456/how-to-setup-apache-server-for-react-route)

You can find more info at this link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History