# " URL" not found for hosted ReactJS website on server when reloading the page

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router, http-status-code-404, web-hosting

I have created a ReactJS application and hosted it on the server using the build file and when I access and the URL every route and the functionality of the webpage is working properly.
But after login I have added a route to dashboard page and after reloading the dashboard page or any routes inside dashboard page after login I'm getting the URL not found message on the webpage.
How can I solve the problem, can anyone help me out with it.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62847325/when-navigating-to-a-url-in-a-react-app-i-get-a-404-but-when-i-follow-a-link-to (although I can't vote to close it because none of the answers have up votes)

Comment: Is your localhost working fine ? Wheredo  you deploy your project linux/windows/netlify or any other ?

Comment: @KhandkerAshikMahmud localhost is working fine but when we go to the link and refresh the page it shows URL not found.