# React js application deployed on godaddy vps but not displaying data

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment, vps

I have my react js application deployed on godaddy vps which has been linked fine but when I tried to load url it doesn't display any data on browser. Can Somebody help me to solve this problem. Thanks  in advance.

[image: Here is screen shot from my browser]

Comment: What does your console display? Maybe your application instantly crashes, resulting in a white screen.

Comment: @Alserda Console only displays this ``` Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' ``` but application works fine on localhost

Comment: I viewed the URL and think it's most likely related due to a mismatch between your virtual router and Apache settings. You need to redirect all traffic to your root: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48872476/3170628. Please try that and let me know.

Comment: @Alserda sure Let me try

Comment: @Alserda I have tried but it doesn't help problem remains same

Comment: Navigating to your `/login` page does render something, so it seems to be something with your `/smartfusion` route. Maybe try to make a build locally and serve it locally (with php -S for example) and try to debug there.

Comment: @Alserda Let me check

Comment: I have solved my problem just by changing sub domain to main domain and its works perfectly now